# Find the one matching set in a number of sets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (@t1) that contains a number of sets. I want to find a perfect match for @t2 in @t1.

In this example, the desired result is 1.

(Set 1 matches perfectly, set 2 contains three elements while @t2 only contains two elements, set 3 contains less elements than @t2, set 4 contains NULL elements which are not allowed in @t2 and set 5 contains the right number of elements but one of the elements is not equal.)

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (id INT, data INT);
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (data INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO @t1 (id, data)
VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 1),
(4, NULL),
(4, NULL),
(5, 1),
(5, 3);

INSERT @t2 (data)
VALUES
(1),
(2);
```

I have a query that *may* be getting the job done, but it looks somehow wretched too me.

```
WITH t1 AS
(
    SELECT id, data
    FROM @t1
    WHERE data IS NOT NULL
),
t1_count AS
(
    SELECT id, RCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM @t1
    WHERE data IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT t1.id
FROM t1
JOIN t1_count ON t1.id = t1_count.id
FULL JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.data = t2.data
WHERE t1_count.RCount = (SELECT RCount = COUNT(*) FROM @t2)
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(t1.data) = COUNT(t2.data);
```

EDIT (GarethD's comment):

```
WITH t1 AS
(
    SELECT
        id,
        data,
        RCount = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id)
    FROM @t1
    WHERE data IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT t1.id
FROM t1
FULL JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.data = t2.data
WHERE t1.RCount = (SELECT RCount = COUNT(*) FROM @t2)
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(t1.data) = COUNT(t2.data);
```

Comment: You can simplify it slightly by adding `Rcount = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id)` to your subquery t1, this eliminates the need for the second cte (`t1_count`), other than that I don't see a simpler, or more efficient way of doing it

Comment: I usually approach tasks like this with EXISTS() / NOT EXISTS().

Comment: @GarethD: I think this makes makes quiet a difference, at least in readability, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called **Exact [Relational Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29)**. Unfortunately, SQL Server has no native operator for this, but it is a well-documented problem. One possible solution (idea taken from [an article by Joe Celko](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)) is to compare counts, similar to what you are already doing:

```
SELECT t1.id
  FROM @t1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN @t2 AS t2 ON t1.data = t2.data
 GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(t1.data) = (SELECT COUNT(data) FROM @t2)
   AND COUNT(t2.data) = (SELECT COUNT(data) FROM @t2);
```

Note that both `HAVING` comparisons are necessary:

- The first one ensures that t1 has exactly the required number of rows and
- the second one ensures that these rows only contain values from t2 (otherwise, `t2.data` would be NULL via the LEFT JOIN. Recall that COUNT(x) only counts non-null values of x).

Comment: Quite shorter code. Which could be prefered for the readability. But it's a bit slower than the code provided by the questioner.

Comment: One way with profiler and a second way with the actual query plan. :-)

Comment: @Ionic: Nice. :-) I'd be careful with profiling on test data, though. I assume that, with real-life data, t1 would have a lot more rows, and t1.id and data would be indexed -- which could lead to an entirely different query plan.

Comment: Yes your right with that. :-) But as always, you can just test what you have not what you might have. :-) But anyway nice short and readable code. :-)

Comment: Good old Joe Celko. First time he ranted at me in a forum was in the 20th century. He certainly would not like that I used table variables in the example code. This looks like an excellent solution, thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to concatenate the values for each `ID` and the values in the second table and compare them. You can apply ordering of the concatenation as well.

For example, the following code will concatenate the values from the second table:

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(MAX) = (

                                SELECT ',' + data
                                FROM @t2 
                                ORDER BY data
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                           ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')

SELECT @test -- 12
```

and the following will do this for the first table:

```
SELECT id
      ,(

            SELECT ',' + data
            FROM @t1 
            WHERE id = t1.id
            ORDER BY data
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
       ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @t1 t1
GROUP BY id
```

[image]

You can filter the values easily with `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT id
          ,(

                SELECT ',' + data
                FROM @t1 
                WHERE id = t1.id
                ORDER BY data
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
           ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') data
    FROM @t1 t1
    GROUP BY id
) DS
WHERE data = @test
```

---

Concatenating values in `T-SQL` does not look `nice`, but you can apply an aggregation concatenation function using `SQL CLR` (check this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx)) and you will have something like this then:

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Test = [dbo].[Concatenate] (data) 
FROM @t2 

SELECT id
FROM @t1 
GROUP BY id
HAVING [dbo].[Concatenate] (data) = @Test
```

Comment: You need to add a `','` to concatenated numbers, so that, say, `12` is not confused with `1` and `2`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, yes, this is very good point. Depending on you data you can concatenate using `,` or something else if you need. The `concatenate` function from the topic is using `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one seems simpler for you?

```
SELECT dat.id
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id as id, t2.data as data2, sourcecount.cnt as scnt, dataCount.cnt as dcnt, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.id) as mcnt
    FROM @t1 as t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT t.id, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM @t1 as t  GROUP BY t.id) as sourceCount
            ON t1.id = sourceCount.id
    INNER JOIN @t2 as t2
            ON t1.data = t2.data
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM @t2) as dataCount
) as dat
WHERE dat.scnt = dat.dcnt AND dat.mcnt = dat.dcnt
GROUP BY dat.id
```

Which produces by the way the same execution plan as yours, but is maybe a bit more readable.

Best regards, Ionic